# Simple binding of XML data to WPF TreeView using XElement

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, treeview, xelement

Its been a while since I've had to mess with the syntax to actually hook up an XML data set using XElement to a WPF TreeView.  I've tried to recreate a pretty simple example, but I get nothing displaying in the TreeView.

Here is my XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" x:Key="ViewEditTreeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1">
            <Label x:Name="ElementHeaderLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Name.LocalName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <TreeView  Name="DataTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewEditTreeTemplate}}" Height="160"  Width="176" />
</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind.

```
XElement Element = XElement.Load("test.xml");
DataTree.DataContext = Element;
```

The "test.xml" is properly formatted and there are no errors while loading it.  I don't understand why nothing displays after I set the data context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set the `ItemTemplate` of the TreeView (you appear to have accidentally set it as `ItemsSource`) and you cannot implicitly apply templates to XML data making it a resource (further you set a Key which prevents that either way).

I think in code behind you should set the `ItemsSource` instead of the `DataContext`, it should be either a list of root elements or a one-element-list containing the root element only.

Comment: Hurray, that was the trick.  2 hours of my life I'll never get back :D.  I've got to  starting committing this stuff to memory.